# How to Read an application text e.g calc through OCR in C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++

i don't want to read from text file instead i want to read an application text e.g calculator buttons,File names on desktop.A generic applicaiton

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe there is a better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Why OCR? You have accessibility API and ui automation api

Answer (score 0):

You could take a screenshot and then use an OCR library such as GOCR or tessnet.

Comment: No, not with the help of screen shot .it is like browsing an image,reading it's data and saving it in text file .I want browsing an application reading an application data like buttons etc and saving it in text file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do it for a screenshot? Or from an actual locally running application?

If from a running app, you can use the native Win32 APIs to locate the handle for the control you wish to read.

Then use send message and WM_GETTEXT to read the text

Comment: Thnx 4 help.I want to do it on actual locally running application.can u plz provide any useful link i will be very thankful.

Comment: Using something like managedspy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx is probably going to the be the easiest, there are some good examples there. Try out the Spy++ program that accompanies Visual Studio to get your head around hWnds and so forth.